# Test for Convergence of a $p$-series

Tags: real-analysis

In many books i see that convergence of a $p$-series when $p>1$ and divergence of a $p$-series when $p$ lies between $0$ and $1$ is proved by either integral test or by Cauchy condensation test. We know Cauchy Criterion for convergence of series is the most basic test for convergence of a series. Can it be done by Cauchy Criterion?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean "Cauchy Criterion"

Comment: yes using cauchy criterion

Answer (score 2):

First prove the following inequality:
$$
\frac{1}{k^p}\le\frac{1}{p-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{(k-1)^{p-1}}-\frac{1}{k^{p-1}}\Bigr).
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{1}{k^p}\le \frac{1}{p-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{(m-1)^{p-1}}-\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}\Bigr).
$$

**Note**: this is the integral test in disguise.